# Object DOMDocument should be created on admin side

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, dom

I have looked a lot but can't find the solution to this issue on my admin side

when I run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` i get errors from 3rd party modules even these modules are off from config.php and also tried permission to genereted and var/di      .........thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I am using docker

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: updated my Question

Comment: yes i have that

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using those 3rd party module, Kindly remove from the project
Otherwise, whenever you run `di:compile` command, you get those error again

Remove Unused observer from events.xml

check controller constructor

Comment: tried this by removing 3rd party module  but now getting error that file does not exit of that 3rd party module that i just removed

Comment: Please disable module before remove from project

Comment: already disabled from config.php

Comment: Post error when you run bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: nope didn't helped this solution `Interceptors generation` error while di:compile

Comment: Post full error sentence while run di:compile

Comment: Clear generated folder and then static-content:deploy command

Comment: rm -rf var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ generated/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: updated my Ques

Comment: by your last comment command i lost my magento file and got `Could not open input file: bin/magento`

Comment: Check your ordercancel oberver exists in those module

Comment: Set file permission. this error will go Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: yes i have that but not in TM folder

Comment: You have two issues. Check you observer still in observer folder and declared in events.xml and second one is extra parameter called in controller constructor

Comment: Check namesapce in observer

Comment: tried to remove that but problem is it goes on showing files. when i remove one file issue it shows me next one and then next and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95576/discussion-between-msa-and-asad-ullah).

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for over two days for the solution. Here i found something that can help

1: make a fresh copy of the site to my local

2: change database credentials from app/etc/env.php

3: rename auth.json.sample to auth.json

4: provide new your magento keys from marketplace in auth.json file

5: run :  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> If you get the error: Can't run this operation: deployment configuration is absent. Its mean you config.php file is missing from app/etc/ location, take following steps.

Either found an existing config.php and copy it to under desired location.
OR Run the command php bin/magento module:enable --all

run :  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

sudo chown -R <Magento user>:<web server group> .

rm -rf var/di var/view_preprocessed var/cache var/page_cache pub/static/frontend generated/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Do run these commands with proper permission.

Comment: tried this but no luck

Comment: So do you have the particular module TM_TrackingOrders still installed

Comment: yes i have that

Comment: the problem is when i clear this one file issue i get another file and then next and so on

Comment: Can you share this file Controller/Adminhtml/Test/Index.php file of that module

Comment: file is to big what specific part

Comment: Are you just trying to set up the working live instance in localhost

Comment: yes exactly i am doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95579/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-asad-ullah).